# WCF error "Sequence contains no elements" - "Collection was Out Of fixed size"

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, nettcpbinding

I am new in WCF. I'm starting to create a WCF project that save people's information in EF database.

I had lots of errors and fixed them by searching in various sites but recently I have been stopped by some errors and can't fix them.

My project is **n-tier with Entity framework** data model. There is 4 layer for server.

**DAL**(Contain EF dataModel)-->**BLL**(Class library for insert/update/Delete Functions)-->**Service Layer**(wcf class library)-->**Host Layer**(windows service)

I host my service in a Windows Service. The service binding is nettcpbinding. I configure service true so no problem here.

i have a Project with name "Common"(class library) that All 4 project access to it and as you know i create a code generator and pasted generated class to common.(Separate class model with DAL).

Now the cient has just (Host Layer) service reference.in client, I have all entity classes in service class.

The problem occurs when I want to insert object to data base. See Code below :

**Server Side (This Is in BLL And Service Layer):**

```
namespace BLL
{
    public static class bz
    {
        public static class People
        {
            public static void myInsert(Common.People p, out bool Result)
            {
                Result = false;

                Common.EFContainer cntx = new Common.EFContainer();
                cntx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                cntx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                if (p.FirstName == "" || p.FirstName == null)
                {
                   throw new Exception("Fill Fist Name") ;
                }
                //  ... more validate
                //-->I Do not use first or single etc in validating<--
                try
                {

                    cntx.Peoples.AddObject(p);
                    cntx.SaveChanges();
                    Result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        public static class Gender
        {
             public static List<Common.Gender> GetData()
             {
                Common.EFContainer cntx = new Common.EFContainer();
                cntx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                cntx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                return cntx.Genders.ToList();
             }
        }
    }
}

namespace ServiceLayer
{

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IService
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(NormalExeption))]
    [OperationContract]
    bool AddToPeople(Common.People p);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Common.Gender> GetGenders();
}

  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode =     System.ServiceModel.ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
 public class myService : IService
 {
    [OperationBehavior]
    public bool AddToPeople(Common.People p)
    {
      try
        {
            BLL.bz.People.myInsert(p, out result);

             return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
           var exep = new NormalExeption(ex.Message, ex.Source, 0, Icons.Error);
           throw new FaultException<NormalExeption>(exep, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText(ex.Message)));
        }
    }
    [OperationBehavior]
    public  List<Common.Gender> GetGenders()
    {
       return BLL.bz.Gender.GetData();
    }
 }
```

}

**Client side :**

```
ServiceRef.People p = new ServiceRef.People();
ServiceRef.myServiceClient client=new ServiceRef.myServiceClient();

p.FirstName="S";

//... Fill Other Fields 

p.Childs=new List<ServiceRef.Child>();
p.Childs.Add(new ServiceRef.Child(){FirstName="A"});

p.Gender=client.GetGenders.first();

//... --->No Error Happen Till Here Error Is After This in Service<---


try
{
  client.AddToPeople(p);
}
Catch(FaultException fe)
{
  messagebox.show(fe.Detail.Message);
}
```

**My Problems :**

Both errors occur in client side after I insert the people object.

When i use Poco Code Generator For My EF I receive this error:

> Collection Was Out Of Fixed Size

This error occurs in poco classes definition.

When I use Self Tracking Code Generator For my EF I receive this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

I think This error occurs in `contex.addobject(p)` and I don't use any `Single` Or `First` in my code that return this exception.

Some one help me - which code generator can I use that doesn't have these errors or how can I fix these errors? I have VS 2010.

Edit: The service works when the server send objects to client but when client inserts it fails. In the client service reference config I changed the collection type to: 
`System.Collection.Generic.List`